# How to define name of foreign key of joined table inheritance strategy?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hsqldb, hibernate-4.x

I am using hbm2ddl from hibernate tools (version 4.3) to generate my ddl script. The name of the foreign key is a generated one, e.g. `FK_14n63malgiroxq6j6efy53skl`.

Is there a way to define the name, e.g. `FK_DOMAIN_EVENT_ID`? I tried with `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and `@ForeignKey` but without success.

Here is the base entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class DomainEvent {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    private Calendar occuredOn;
}
```

Here the extended class:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_DOMAIN_EVENT_ID"))
public class OrderSubmittedEvent extends DomainEvent {

    private String orderId;

}
```

And here the generated output with the generated foreign key `FK_14n63malgiroxq6j6efy53skl`:

```sql
create table domain_event (
    id binary(255) not null,
    occured_on timestamp,
    primary key (id)
);

create table order_submitted_event (
    order_id varchar(255),
    id binary(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
);

alter table order_submitted_event 
    add constraint FK_14n63malgiroxq6j6efy53skl 
    foreign key (id) 
    references domain_event;
```